# Restoring backup on new computer

Tags: server, backup, restore

I have been following [this tutorial on Ubuntu forums for backup/restore of ubuntu server](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087)

I have a dedicated server and in case I have to restore the whole server on a new machine, I'm practicing using a virtual machine in vmware.

I've managed to restore all the files by doing an untar of the backup. However I can't get apache to start:

```
could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name using 127.0.1.1 for servername
```

and

```
The Apache error log may have more information
```

The problem is that there are no logs since I've excluded them from the backup.

Do I need to first install Apache and then untar the backup ?

Is this the proper way to restore the server ? I have some doubts because things like ip address and host name would be different if I create a new dedicated server, so there is potentially a significant number of files that would need to be updated. Is there a recommended way to do that?

Comment: It depends what you backed up. When I backup my server I only keep the actual pages, not the configuration, because the config will be different.

Comment: I've excluded these : --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tgz

Comment: I would extract them to a directory that you make, and then copy across the ones that you need, rather than a direct extraction.

Comment: I could do that easily with files such as the ones in /var/www. However, I can't remember all the configuration files that I might have configured such as the ones for apache, ufw, etc.... That's why I though I'd just copy everything over.

Comment: Well if you've just reinstalled, try it. If it fails, reinstall again, and then just copy /var/www ?

Answer (score 0):

I've manually created the log directory and next time I attempted to start Apache, the error.log file was created.

From there, I could find out that there was no entry in the /etc/hosts file for the new machine's name. I created it and now Apache runs fine.

I'm still wondering if this the proper way to set up a new server out of a backup tar ?